Node to constrain Parent link with respect to the child link
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

class JointConstrainer(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('joint_constrainer')
        
        # Publisher for joint2's command
        self.joint2_pub = self.create_publisher(Float64, '/robot/joint2_position_controller/command', 10)
        
        # Subscriber for the joint states
        self.joint_state_sub = self.create_subscription(
            JointState,
            '/joint_states',
            self.joint_state_callback,
            10)
        
        # Store joint positions
        self.joint1_position = 0.0

    def joint_state_callback(self, msg):
        try:
            # Get the index of joint1 and joint2
            joint1_index = msg.name.index('Right_End_Frame_Joint')
            joint2_index = msg.name.index('Spring_Joint_1')
            
            # Get the position of joint1
            self.joint1_position = msg.position[joint1_index]
            
            # Compute the constrained position for joint2
            joint2_position = self.joint1_position * 10.0
            
            # Create a new JointState message to publish only the constrained joint2 position
            constrained_msg = JointState()
            constrained_msg.header = msg.header  # Copy the header
            constrained_msg.name = [msg.name[joint2_index]]
            constrained_msg.position = [joint2_position]
            constrained_msg.velocity = [0.0]  # Assuming velocity is 0
            constrained_msg.effort = [0.0]  # Assuming effort is 0

            # Publish the constrained joint2 position
            self.joint2_pub.publish(Float64(data=joint2_position))
        except ValueError:
            self.get_logger().warn("Joint names 'Right_End_Frame_Joint' or 'Spring_Joint_1' not found in joint states")

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    
    joint_constrainer = JointConstrainer()
    
    rclpy.spin(joint_constrainer)
    
    joint_constrainer.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

In the above code,I am simply trying create a node that constrains the motion of the parent link(Spring_Joint_1) with respect to the child link(Right_End_Frame_Joint). I am new to ROS, so this is mostly with the help of ChatGPT but the overall node looked good. In the end, I can see that the joint value is being published under the topic, /robot/joint2_position_controller/command but I'd like that to be communicated to Spring_Joint_1 and see the changes in the rviz visual window. Currently I do not see the changes in Spring_joint_1 as I change Right_End_Frame.Any suggestions would be helpful.
